# How best to email a professor to set up a meeting after a long time?

Tags: masters, email, research-assistantship

My path to get my MA was delayed following a family tragedy, and I'm finally in a position where I can get back on track, so I would like to reach out to a professor I previously did lab work for a couple years ago. I have some general questions for him, but I also would like to see if maybe he has a Research Assistant position available, or maybe knows other professors that might, to try to build up my experience again. I was wondering if anyone might know the best way to approach an email like this? I was thinking maybe starting by formally asking if he remembered me and maybe giving some details about the work I did for him, but then I don't know where to go from there. I'd prefer to meet in person, but is that okay to ask after such a long time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @scaaahu Although this is based on a fairly specific situation.

Comment: @skymningen The linked question is meant to be a _general_ question about how to communicate to a professor.

Comment: @scaaahu That's the point. I feel this question is less about the communication part (how to formulate the email), but more about "is it okay to ask for a meeting in person".

Comment: @skymningen surely that is difficult for anyone to answer, as we don't know the professor in question and how they would react. *In general*, the answer to this question is yes, email them and the question linked as duplicate answers how to do that.